# Stochastic Integral form

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a silly question.

I know that the stochastic differential equation in derivative form is : $$d X_{t} = aX_{t}dt +b X_{t}dB_{t}$$
can be written is the integral form as $$X_{t}-X_{0} = a \int_{0}^{t}X_{s}ds +b\int_{0}^{t}X_{s}dB_{s}$$.
Now I have in derivative form the : $$d X_{t} = -(a+b^2X_{t})(1-X_{t}^2)dt +b(1- X_{t}^2)dB_{t}$$.
How can I write it in the integral form ?
Any help?

Maybe :

$$-(a+b^2X_{t})(1-X_{t}^2) = -a +aX_{t}^2 - b^2X_{t}+b^2X_{t}^3$$

So .. ?
$$X_{t}-X_{0} =  ?  +b\int_{0}^{t}1 - X_{s}^2dB_{s}  $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form $dX=a(X)dt+b(X)dW$ stands for
$$
X_t-X_0=\int_0^t a(X_s)ds+\int_0^tb(X_s)dW_s
$$
as well as any
$$
\int_0^tc(X_s)dX_s=\int_0^t c(X_s)a(X_s)ds+\int_0^tc(X_s)b(X_s)dW_s
$$
for any sufficiently regular function $c$.

---

So in your specific case you just get
$$
X_T-X_0 = -\int_0^T(a+b^2X_{t})(1-X_{t}^2)dt +\int_0^T b(1- X_{t}^2)dB_{t}
$$
but also, as example,
$$
\int_0^T\frac{dX_t}{1-X_t^2} = -\int_0^T(a+b^2X_{t}) dt +\int_0^T b dB_{t}
$$

Comment: ok but if I want to take out from the first integral the $a$ and $b$ coefficient what  the form will be?

Comment: The integral is still a linear operation, so you can apply the usual distribution laws. But that alone will not be very helpful.